# Propiedad json con varios párrafos

Tags: javascript, json

tengo la siguiente duda: ¿se puede crear una propiedad json con diferentes párrafos?

```
var usuarios = [
      {
        Nombre: "Usuario 1",
        Comentario: "Primer párrafo" + "Segundo párrafo" + "Tercer párrafo",
      },
      {
        Nombre: "Usuario 2",
        Comentario: "Primer párrafo" + "Segundo párrafo" + "Tercer párrafo",
      },

];
```

¿Es válido utilizar la etiqueta p?

```
Comentario: "<p>Primer párrafo</p>" + "<p>Segundo párrafo</p>" + "<p>Tercer párrafo</p>",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var usuarios = [
      {
        Nombre: "Usuario 1",
        Comentario: "<p>Primer párrafo</p>" + "<p>Segundo párrafo</p>" + "<p>Tercer párrafo</p>",
      },
      {
        Nombre: "Usuario 2",
        Comentario: "<p>Primer párrafo</p>" + "<p>Segundo párrafo</p>" + "<p>Tercer párrafo</p>",
      },
];

usuarios.forEach(usuario =>{
  document.body.innerHTML += usuario.Comentario;
});
```

Creo que eso resuelve tu duda, asi que si, si es posible lo que planteas y es totalmente valido, pero deberas usar propiedades especializadas para agregar `HTML` renderizable a tu `HTML` ya que por ejemplo si hubiesemos usado `innerText` en vez de `innerHTML` el mismo código no hubiese hecho lo que esperas:

```js
var usuarios = [
      {
        Nombre: "Usuario 1",
        Comentario: "<p>Primer párrafo</p>" + "<p>Segundo párrafo</p>" + "<p>Tercer párrafo</p>",
      },
      {
        Nombre: "Usuario 2",
        Comentario: "<p>Primer párrafo</p>" + "<p>Segundo párrafo</p>" + "<p>Tercer párrafo</p>",
      },
];

usuarios.forEach(usuario =>{
  document.body.innerText += usuario.Comentario;
});
```

Ademas te propongo una cosa mas para hacerte la vida mas facil, y es que desde `ES6` existe algo llamado `template strings` o tambien llamadas `plantillas de cadenas de texto` en español, las cuales tienen diferentes particularidades, como por ejemplo que respetan los saltos de linea, tabulaciones y espacios que hagas al pie de la letra.

Ademas sin mencionar que dentro de ellos podras usar ciertos caracteres especiales que te permitiran renderizar el valor de codigo javascript dentro de estas, por ejemplo variables o llamadas a funciones.

Entonces aquello que viste usando `template strings` puede resumirse a esto:

```js
var usuarios = [
      {
        Nombre: "Usuario 1",
        Comentario: 
        `Primer párrafo
        Segundo párrafo
        Tercer párrafo`
      },
      {
        Nombre: "Usuario 2",
        Comentario:
        `Primer párrafo
        Segundo párrafo
        Tercer párrafo`
      },

];

usuarios.forEach(usuario =>{
  document.body.innerText += usuario.Comentario;
});
```

**Notese que ahora no podremos usar innerHTML, ya que este no renderizara los saltos de linea usando template strings, pero innerText respetara los saltos de linea de nuestros template strings.**

Otro ejemplo de uso de los `template strings` por si te interesa:

```js
const nombre = "Bill Gates";
const edad = 46;

const message = `Hola!, mi nombre es ${nombre} y tengo ${edad} years`;
console.log(message);
```

Como vemos son muy utiles los `template strings`.

Notese que no es lo mismo usar template strings para definir saltos de linea que usar etiquetas `<p>` que se renderizaran.

Puesto que los template strings **NO** van a crear esas etiquetas, el texto quedara sin rodearse de ninguna etiqueta mas que la principal.